# boost property_tree: iterating through attributes of repeated child elements within repeated child elements

Tags: xml, boost, boost-propertytree, child-nodes

I have the following XML document:

```xml
<root>
  <scenario name="ScenarioA">
    <param name="ParamA">1</param>
    <param name="ParamB">2</param>
    <param name="ParamC">3</param>
  </scenario>
  <scenario name="ScenarioB">
    <param name="ParamA">1</param>
    <param name="ParamB">2</param>
    <param name="ParamC">3</param>
  </scenario>
  <scenario name="ScenarioC">
    <param name="ParamA">1</param>
    <param name="ParamB">2</param>
    <param name="ParamC">3</param>
  </scenario>
</root>
```

Using `boost::property_tree::ptree`, I can do the following to iterate through the top-level elements:

```
ptree scenarioTree = myTree.get_child("root");
for (const auto& itr : scenarioTree) {
    if (itr.second.get<std::string>(<xmlattr>.name) == "ScenarioA") {
        // additional logic
    }
}
```

I am unable to retrieve any attributes of the "param" tags under each scenario, using the same method on `itr.second`:

```
ptree scenarioTree = myTree.get_child("root");
for (const auto& itr : scenarioTree) {
    if (itr.second.get<std::string>(<xmlattr>.name) == "ScenarioA") {
        ptree paramTree = itr.second;
        // Iterate through "param" tags
        for (const auto& paramItr: paramTree) {
            if (paramItr.second.get<std::string>(<xmlattr>.name) == "ParamA") {
                // doesn't exist
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? My theory is this a casting issue between what the ptree iterator returns (self) versus a standard ptree, but I'm not sure how else to retrieve the inner child attributes. I am able to retrieve param tag names (via first) and param values (via second.data()), just no attributes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Attributes in property tree are added as sub-nodes.
Below node can be translated

```
  <scenario name="ScenarioA">
    <param name="ParamA">1</param>
    <param name="ParamB">2</param>
    <param name="ParamC">3</param>
  </scenario>
```

into something like this:

```
  scenario 
     xmlattr.name   ScenarioA // this node doesn't have subnode with attribute name
     param 
       xmlattr.name  -> ParamA
     param 
       xmlattr.name  -> ParamB
     param 
       xmlattr.name  -> ParamC
```

When you found scenario with `ScenarioA` as attribute you are iterating over its children. This node has 4 children. For each child you want to find `name` attribute, but one of them doesn't have this attribute. Method `get` throws exception when path cannot be found. You can catch this exception or use default-value:

```
boost::property_tree::ptree scenarioTree = pt.get_child("root");
for (const auto& itr : scenarioTree) 
{
    if (itr.second.get<std::string>("<xmlattr>.name") == "ScenarioA") 
    {
        boost::property_tree::ptree paramTree = itr.second;
        for (const auto& paramItr: paramTree) 
        {
            if (paramItr.second.get<std::string>("<xmlattr>.name","") == "ParamA") 
            {                                                    ^^^^ default value
                cout << "ParamA was found in ScenarioA" << endl;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

as result I got *ParamA was found in ScenarioA*.

Comment: Thank you so much. This makes sense now, I was wondering if the attributes were missing, but instead my overall try/catch stopped the iteration at the first (empty) attempt.